# CSS Grid: Mobile in text, desktop aside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Consider the following example, the first is the intended desktop look, the second is the mobile one. ([image: Grid style]

What is your recommendation to achieve that using a common grid system w/ media queries like twitter BS or Zurb Foundation?

Answer (score 0):

With Foundation I will do something like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6">
        <div class="small-12">Title</div>
        <div class="small-12 show-for-small">IMG</div>
        <div class="small-12">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 hide-for-small">
        IMG
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have to put "IMG" twice.